# Songs similar to 'Atheist Runt' and 'Omnipresent knife in your back'

Tags: similar-artists, metal, identify-this-genre

I'm looking for recommendations of songs similar to [*Atheist Runt*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VC18orcB1I) and [*Omnipresent knife in your back*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ey3MJkt9-6U). Both these songs were made by Napalm Death and are their only ones which I like.

I find the distinct musical style involving doomish vocals and heavy rhythms in these two songs fascinating.

Comment: celtic frost, godflesh, atriarch, neurosis

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked Swans? At the time of these recordings, they talked about being heavily influenced by them. Haven't listened much to Swans, but they do have some pretty heavy recordings...

Answer (score 2):

These aren't exactly along the same lines, but let's try...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjhEo0MWDJU - Melvins - *Sacrifice*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IRM-ChUt4M - Killing Joke - *Loose Cannon*

Comment: I love doom metal and so I think 'Lysol' is a good album. But the two songs I mentioned are a bit heavier with dragged out and creepy doom-ish vocals. Napalm Death made these experimental tracks which are mostly not well-received among their grindcore fans! Finding songs of style very similar to them is very hard I guess! Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 1):

Alongside SWANS you should also have a look at early Godflesh (the S/T album especially) and Justin Broadrick's more recent project Jesu.